# Using AKMixer with volume lower 0.00001 there is no output

Tags: audiokit

We are using two AKMixer (one for left, one for right channel) and one AKMixer as output with these two mixers as inputs. 
If one of the mixers has a volume lower than 0.00001 the output signal is lost. But lower volumes are possible, because if we lower the main system volume on values over 0.00001 the signal on the headphone-jack is going lower.

As a workaround I tried to set the AKMixer.output.volume to 0.5 and the input mixers to 0.00001 and it works too. But in my application I also need max output and than I got weird "clicks" when changing the both volume levels at once.

It would be great if somebody can help. With the workaround or the causing problem.
Thanks.

```
var rightSine = AKOscillator(waveform: AKTable(.sine))

var rightPanner : AKMixer!

let pan2 = AKPanner(self.rightSine, pan: 1)
pan2.rampDuration = 0
let right1: AKMixer = AKMixer(pan2 /*, ....  some more */)
self.rightPanner = right1


let mix = AKMixer(self.rightPanner /* left channel... */)
mix.volume = 1.0
AudioKit.output = mix


do {
   try AudioKit.start()

} catch {
}

self.rightPanner.volume = 0.00002
```

This is the code used to initialise the audio stuff (shortened) and afterwards the nodes are started.

*Edit: I'm testing the precise threshold on which the output is broken..

Comment: Can you show us what you have done? Please edit your question and add relevant code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AudioKit's AKMixer is a simple wrapper around Apple's AVAudioMixerNode and as such, I can't really dig much deeper to help you solve the problem using that node. But, if you're willing to switch to AKBooster, whose job it is to amplify or diminish a signal, I think you will be fine to use small numbers for your gain value.

```
var rightSine = AKOscillator(waveform: AKTable(.sine))

var rightBooster: AKBooster!

let pan2 = AKPanner(self.rightSine, pan: 1)
pan2.rampDuration = 0
let right1: AKMixer = AKMixer(pan2 /*, ....  some more */)
self. rightBooster = AKBooster(right1)


let mix = AKMixer(self. rightBooster /* left channel... */)
mix.volume = 1.0
AudioKit.output = mix

self.rightBooster.gain = 0.00002
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this, I'll do some more testing but it seems to work now.